# John and I live ten minutes away on foot

Tags: sentence-choice

I think it's clear to say things like this.

(1) John and I live ten minutes away by car.

(2) John and I live ten minutes away by bus.

What about something like this?

(3) John and I live ten minutes away on foot.

"On foot" could mean walking, jogging or sprinting.

I have written down two examples to specify one of them.

(4) John and I live ten minutes away by jogging.

(5) John and I live ten minutes away if we jog.

Which one is correct (4) or (5)?

Comment: *By foot* works just as well as *on foot*. You could also say *It's a ten-minute (walk / jog / run) to where John and I live from here.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these examples give rough estimations. "On foot" would mean walking in most reasonable contexts.

Your examples are grammatically correct, but the second is slightly odd:

> John and I live 10 minutes away if we jog.

Saying "we jog" suggests that you both jog together". If you are going to visit John, then you both don't need to jog! Also, using "away" is slightly odd.  You mean "away from each other". But "apart" would be a better word to use, or rephrase. I would write:

> John lives 10 minutes from me if I jog.

There are, of course, hundreds of other correct ways to give a similar meaning.

> I sometimes jog round to John's house, as he only lives 10 minutes away.

Comment: Off topic probably, but are you sure the OP's "away" is OK? I'd use "apart" or something. To me their sentences read like "John and I both live 10 minutes from here."

Comment: @MrLister Good suggestion. I do think that the OP means "apart".

Comment: Thanks, James K. Yes, I actually meant "apart". Just to confirm this, does it sound OK to say "John and I live ten minutes apart by jogging."